# css3 gradient animation only works on google chrome

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I found [Animate.css](http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) site which comprises a header with gradient animation but gradient animation only works on chrome, it does not have css animation properties for other browsers. do other browsers support this feature ? if answer is yes, what other properties could be added. here code:

```
<h1 class="site__title mega">Animate.css</h1>

.site__title {
    color: #f35626;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(92deg,#f35626,#feab3a);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    -webkit-animation: hue 60s infinite linear;
  }

@-webkit-keyframes hue {
  from {
    -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(0deg);
  }

  to {
    -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(-360deg);
  }
}
```

Comment: You have only used the webkit prefix...you will have to use the other(s) too.

Comment: I know, just dont know how to added other prefixes

Comment: I don't feel writing an answer right now so I leave this as a comment. Actually they are not animating the background image which is defined by `linear-gradient` notation, but the `filter` property. CSS filters were implemented in Webkit-based web browsers but now added to Firefox 35 as well (without any prefixes). Therefore the browser support is limited as of writing. Here's a demo which I couldn't test it in my FF browser, but give it a try if you have FF35: http://jsbin.com/kudoco/1/edit